# Single DIV refreshed - e.preventDefault();

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

When a user search items in `<div class="searchBar">` I want to `POST` the data to `<div id="auto">` and get only `<div id="auto">` refreshed rather than reloading the full page.

My problem is that when the Submit button is clicked, the entire page is loading. I need to be able to refresh only `<div id="auto">` when the submit button is clicked. The main purpose is that I want to avoid `<div class="menuList">` being reloaded every time Submit is clicked. Below is my code.

```
 <div class="searchBar">
 <form action="" method="post">
    Furniture item: 
    <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1" value="<?=$_POST['val1']?>" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="menuList">
    List of Furniture: 
    <select id='myList' name="mList" onchange='document.getElementById("val1").value = this.value;'><option value="">Furniture Available</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        refresh();    
        });
    function refresh(){
        $("#submit").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'php/filep.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#submit').val,
                success: function(data, status) {
                    $("#result").html(data)
                }
            });
            $(".result").fadeOut("slow");
            refresh();  
        });
    }
    </script>
 </body>
```

filep.php

```
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
    $resData = htmlentities('img/'.$_POST['val1']).'/'; 
}
if( isset($resData) ) {
$files = '*.*';
$fin = glob($resData.$files);
    $counts = count($fin);
    $imgs = array();
$div= '';
foreach ($imgs as $fin) {       
        $div .= '<div class="imgSlots">';
        $div .= '<li><div class="imgSlotsInner"><input type="image" src="'.$fin.'"/><testDes>"'.basename($fin.$files).'"</testDes></div></li>';
        $div .= '</div>';  
    }
echo $div;
}
```

Comment: Look for `JS` errors in your browser's console and solve them.

Comment: instead of the assigning on the submit. you could do something like: `<form action="" method="post" id="myform">`, then `$("#myform").submit(function(e)` then `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Why did you put your click event handler inside a function and call that function again in the same click handler? Also note there is no element with an ID of `result`

Comment: Change the submit button type to simple button. Submit will call the page reload. Or try to use onsubmit function

Answer (score 2):

yes you can refresh the single div only. what exactly you need to do is refresh the html of that div i.e.  first delete the html of that div like

$('#auto').html('');

and then put you content again what you have fetched from the Ajax posting in that Div. like if you are going to refresh a Grid or table just write the inline HTML and fill all the data coming from ajaxpost. You may use .each method to make it in loop

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Harjeet. you mean like this?   `data: $('#submit').val, success: function(data, status) { $("#result").html(''); $("#result").html(data); }` Did not work?

Comment: yes . this works for me. please try once. what you are getting in your ajax data?    try to use $.each(data,function(index,item){} and write you li and div html inside it. you may also use append method at the end of every occurence of a look that will append li and div structure as much as your loop. means if your loop runs three times. three li's and divs will be appended

Comment: It still reloads the entire page. Also I tried `<button type="button" onclick="refresh();">Submit</button>` and adjusted the JS like this `function refresh(){ e.preventDefault(); $.ajax({` That did not work either.

Comment: According to my code in my question, is the search text `value="<?=$_POST['val1']?>"` being passed correctly? `<input type="text" name="val1" id="val1" value="<?=$_POST['val1']?>" />`

Comment: actually i am a dot net developer so i am not familiar with php code

Comment: Thanks anyway Harjeet.